# How to make blob specific version as current version using PowerShell or cli

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-storage

I have versioning enabled on storage account. I would like to make specific blob version as a current version using powershell or cli. Please find the attached screenshot herewith.Thanks.

[image]

Required a powershell or cli script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell Cmdlet you would want to use is [`Copy-AzStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/copy-azstorageblob?view=azps-10.0.0). The source blob URL you would be using would be the one of the blob version (something like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob?versionid=<blob-version>`) Your code would be something like:

```
$sourceBlobUri = "Blob URL with version"
Copy-AzStorageBlob -AbsoluteUri $sourceBlobUri -DestContainer "container" -DestBlob "blob"
```

Comment: The answer is *almost* correct. It took me a good hour to find out that absolute uri should contain `versionId`, not `version`.  Then it started working.

Comment: @TomBurger - Thanks. You are correct. Updated my answer based on your comments.